# Fastcgi error - FastCgiIpcDir problems in error log

Tags: apache2, fastcgi

FastCgiIpcDir problems in error log

Hi,

I have noticed in my Apache error logs the following error (error 1):

```
[Wed Feb 08 14:00:06 2012] [alert] [client 41.185.88.175] (2)No such file or  directory: FastCGI: failed to connect to (dynamic) server "/var/www/bin/php-splashpage-user/php-fastcgi": something is seriously wrong, any chance the socket/named_pipe directory was removed?, see the FastCgiIpcDir directive
```

Directly afterwards followed by this error (error 2):

```
[Wed Feb 08 14:00:06 2012] [error] [client 41.185.88.175] FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server "/var/www/bin/php-splashpage-user/php-fastcgi"
```

How do I fix error 1?

I read about changing this due to the host system cleaning out the "/tmp" directory ( the default dir for fastCgiIpcDir if not defined ) periodically and thus obliterating communication with current active FastCGI services. So I decided to give it a go. I set the FastCgiIpcDir in fastcgi.conf file in hopes of success, but there is simply no change.

This is the contents of my fastcgi.conf file:

```
<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
    FastCgiIpcDir /var/lib/apache2/fastcgi_test
    FastCgiConfig -idle-timeout 60 -maxClassProcesses 1
    FastCgiWrapper On

    AddHandler php5-fcgi .php
    Action php5-fcgi /cgi-bin/php-fastcgi

    <Location "/cgi-bin/php-fastcgi">
            Order Deny,Allow
            Deny from All
            Allow from env=REDIRECT_STATUS
            Options ExecCGI
            SetHandler fastcgi-script
    </Location>
</IfModule>
```

Permissions and onwerships of /var/lib/apache2/fastcgi_test:

```
drwxr-xr-x  3 www-data www-data 4.0K 2012-02-08 09:20 fastcgi_test
```

My php wrapper script php_fastcgi has the following lines:

```
#!/bin/sh

PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN=120
export PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN
PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS=1000
export PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS

umask 0022
exec /usr/bin/php-cgi -d apc.shm_size=50
```

I am running PHP 5.3.1, Apache/2.2.14, Ubuntu 10.04.

Here's few things I've picked up so far:

- Error 1 only appears at the beginning of an hour say 6 seconds just after the new hour

From working with mod_FastCgi I have learnt that increasing the child processes help relieve some of the "error 2" errors ( which cause the HTTP 500 error at random intervals). Currently I am not quite sure what the affect of error 1 would be, however if error 2 follows directly after then it's safe to say it's not a good thing.

There is very little, if any, full information on errors reported by Fastcgi with tried and tested solutions. Sadly I may just be adding onto the piles of Fastcgi errors posted on the web with no conclusion.

Your help, advice or tips in resolving error 1 would be readily appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to make it work with a wrapper, and suexec, but you should try this:

http://blog.kmp.or.at/2013/06/apache-2-2-on-debian-wheezy-w-php-fpm-fastcgi-apc-and-a-kind-of-suexec/

The solution in the link does not even use suexec, nor the wrapper, and that way at least it works.

The steps required for that:

0) install php5-fpm, and apache-mpm-worker if not already installed

1) comment this line :

```
#FastCgiWrapper On
```

2) make an alias:

```
Alias /cgi-bin/php-fastcgi **/var/something**
```

3) fastcgiexternalserver:

```
FastCgiExternalServer **/var/something** -socket php5-fpm-site1user.sock
```

(The strongly typed paths must be the same)

4) set up the conf in php5-fpm/pool.d/site1user.conf

```
[site1user]
user = site1user
group = site1user

listen = /var/run/php5-fpm-site1user.sock

pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 5
pm.start_servers = 2
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 3

chdir = /
```

5) restart fpm
    service php5-fpm restart

6) for deeper understanding check my other answer here

https://serverfault.com/questions/524708/php5-fpm-apache2-on-wheezy-connect-failed-with-fastcgi/536277#536277

Comment: On the error, what file/directory would "*(2)No such file or directory*" be referring to?

Comment: Got it. *(2)No such file or directory* was caused by the missing socket file because my **PHP5-FPM** was not starting due to an error in configuration. I only figured out the error by running `php5-fpm` manually and *not* using the service.

Running services manually has actually proven to be for good debugging in the past as well, because sometimes using `sudo service ... start` gives no feedback.